# Java implementing scheduler errors on normal function

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

Currently I have my java application where I called the the function from the main and there after all is done in it. Below is snippet of my codes. So I need to run the calling of the function on a timely basis and read about scheduler. So I have tried to implement it in my main function and got error: 'void' type not allowed here `final ScheduledFuture<?> timeHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(ws1TI(), 0, 10);` Any solution to this issue "?

```
public class ws1TI
{
public static void ws1TI()
      {
            try
            {
             SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
             SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
             String url = "http://*********.asmx?WSDL";
             SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);
             printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);
             updateAcknoledgement();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
      }
      public static     void main(String[] args)
      {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();   
        final ScheduledFuture<?> timeHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(ws1TI(), 0, 10); 

      }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scheduleAtFixedRate` should receive a [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html), not a void value. You could, for example, convert your `ws1TI` function to a `Runnable` like so:

```
public class ws1TI {
    public static class WS1TI implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                 SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
                 SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
                 String url = "http://*********.asmx?WSDL";
                 SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);
                 printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);
                 updateAcknoledgement();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();   
        final ScheduledFuture<?> timeHandle = 
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new WS1TI(), 0L, 10L, TimeUnits.MINUTE); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried you method I dont understand why will need 2 public class ws1TI where one is static? Secondly I got this error required: Runnable,long,long,TimeUnit
  found: WS1TI,int,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Comment: The first parameter is an instance of a `Runnable` with the code you want to run, the last one, which I indeed had missing, is the an instance of `TimeUnits` that explains how to interpret the rate you supplied. I edited my answer accordingly, using minutes.

Comment: I infact tried earlier too and again got this error now  symbol:   variable TimeUnits
  location: class ws1TI
1 error
. Must I change this public static class WS1TI implements Runnable { class name to something else is it that we have put one class outside public class ws1TI {. Must the Runnable class cover all function which is being called by the run function ?